# Copy vertical text block in Vim on Mac

Tags: vim, vi

How do I copy a vertical text block in vim on a Mac?

On a PC on would just do ctrl-c at starting point and ctrl-c at the end point and it would copy between these two coordinates. How do I do that on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if Vim under Mac is different, but in Linux you can do this - press `Ctrl+V` to enter VISUAL BLOCK mode, then select usually (e.g. move with `hjkl`), then `y` to yank when done.

Comment: Awesome. Didnt know there was a visual block mode.